# Pointers and structures and pointers again... when creating a stack

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

So, I wanted to create a stack as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
        int data;
        struct node *link;
}node;

typedef struct Stack{
        struct Node *topnode;
        int count;
}stack;

void push(int data, stack *ourstack){
    node newnode;
    newnode.data = data;
    ourstack.topnode = &newnode;
}

int main()
{
    stack mystack;
    push(1,mystack);
    printf("%d",(mystack.(*topnode).data));


}
```

but I do get errors. I am a bit confused here. Inside the `push()` function, in the last line, I tried various ways of implementing it right but I failed each time. Now, my thinking is, `ourstack` is a pointer pointing to a `struct Stack`. And the `topnode` is also a pointer inside a structure of a stack which points to another node structure. So, should not `(*ourstack).(*topnode) = newnode` or `ourstack.topnode = &newnode` work? Why?

Comment: "I do get errors" - what errors?

Comment: request for member 'topnode' in something not a structure or union  in `ourstack.topnode = &newnode` @JohnZwinck

Comment: `struct Node` -> `struct node` , `ourstack.topnode` -> `ourstack->topnode`, `push(1, mystack);` -> `push(1, &mystack);`, `(mystack.(*topnode).data)` -> `mystack.topnode->data` and a few more problems.

Comment: Hint: open your C text book and read the chapters dealing with dynamic memory allocation and with pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither work because `newnode` is on the stack and once the code exits `push`, it will no longer exist. You need to allocate it dynamically.

```
void push(int data, stack *ourstack){
    node *newnode;
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
    newnode->next = ourstack->topnode; // Point the next of the new node to the top node of the stack
    newnode->data = data;
    ourstack->topnode = newnode;
}
```

And also you need to initialise `mystack` properly in `main` or else you risk undefined behaviour as `topnode` could be `NULL` or it could have a random value.

```
stack mystack;
mystack.topnode = NULL;
mystack.count = 0;
```

Comment: I see, and should it be `push(1,mystack)`?

Comment: and if I want to print the topnode of my stack, `printf("%d",&(mystack.(*topnode).data));` ?

Comment: no - `mystack` is declared as `stack` and `push` is expecting a `stack *` - a pointer to `stack`, so you need to call it `push(1,&mystack)`

Comment: And printing the value uses `mystack.topnode->data`

Comment: you use `.` for structs and `->` for pointers to structs. You shouldn't need to use `*` or `&` in such cases as it makes the code unreadable

Comment: It isn't a `struct node` though - it's a `struct Node` or it's `node` - that's the problem with using different capitalisation of the names - you should stick to just one style to prevent such confusion

Comment: Yeah, just realized that. Thanks a billion for summing up everything so briefly.

Comment: struct Node *topnode should be struct node *topnode

Answer (score 2):

variable in a method, only exists in stack, will be unavailable after exit method. since you wish keep it after call of `push`, you need alloc a node with function like `malloc`, which will save data in heap. and you have to `free` it after you do not need it any more.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of bugs in your program.

- `ourstack` is `pointer` variable of `structure` type, while accessing data using ourstack use `->` operator instead of `dot` operator

  Replace

  ```
  ourstack.topnode = &newnode;
  ```

  with

  ```
  ourstack->topnode = &newnode;
  ```
- there is a conflict in push function `definition` and function call, you are passing just `mystack` and catching with `struct pointer` variable. pass the `address` of `mystack`, your function call should be

  ```
  push(1,&mystack);
  ```
- `newnode` is the local variable declared in `push` function and whatever you are trying with `newnode` it will reflects in this function only, not outside of this. So Allocate memory dynamically for `newnode` and do the operation.

  ```
  void push(int data, stack *ourstack){
      node *newnode;
      newnode = malloc(sizeof(stack));
      newnode->data = data;
      ourstack->topnode = newnode;
  }
  ```

Once compiled successfully debug the code using `gdb` and analyze.

Comment: So, if I want to access to the first element of the stack, should I be doing `mystack.topnode->data` or `mystack->topnode.data` ? because neither works when I want to print it `printf("%d",mystack.topnode->data);`

Comment: simply do `printf("%d\n", (mystack.topnode)->data);`